# PHP array of generated options?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this code:

```
$prod = "";
$vys = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vys)) {
   $prod .= "<option value='".$arr['id_produktu']."'>".$arr['nazev']."</option>";               
}
```

and I want to have an array of this options where every array field is one of the id_type. But I'm a bit scared of using loop in loop :( It would technically look like this:

```
    $prod = "";
    $types = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id_type FROM products");
    while ($ts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($types)) {
        $res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_type=$ts['id_type'] ORDER BY name");
        while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $prod[$arr['id_type']] = "<option value='".$arr['id_produktu']."'>".$arr['nazev']."</option>";               
        }
    }
```

So I can later call (via pressed button value) an exact array of options according to the id_type value.
Like this (using JS):

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function setContent(divName, type){
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = \"<select name=idp[]>$prod[type]</select>\";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Do you think it's possible without using loop in loop? ;) Thank you :)

Comment: Get all the query results outside your loop with one join request and then just go over the received array. Using query in a loop is **always** a bad idea.

Comment: "*Do you think it's possible without using loop in loop?*"... yes, it's called an `INNER JOIN`. Standard SQL syntax. Plenty of [examples on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+inner+join).

Comment: @DainisAbols: I don't think I can process the MySQL result without a loop (mysql_fetch_assoc) :(

Comment: @Spudley: I have two tables with products from which I first need the list of types so I can put them in array and second I need to filter them by the type to the appropriorate $prod['id_type'] variable. Where can I possibly use JOIN with two same tables? ;)

Comment: Have you heard of `GROUP BY` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prod = array();
$vys = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vys)) {
   $prod[$arr['id_type']][] = "<option value='".$arr['id_produktu']."'>".$arr['nazev']."</option>";             
}
```

Now prod is array of options, containing your products.

Later, to use it like a string you need to implode it.

```
echo implode(' ', $prod['some type']);
```

Comment: Thanks VG, but then, in JS, isn't it the array to string conversion problem? 
function setContent(divName, type){
..
newdiv.innerHTML = \"<select name=idp[]>$prod[type]</select>\";
..

Comment: See second code block in my response. Use implode, it will return the string.

Comment: Thanks VG, but I didn't find a possible variety how can insert php code into JavaScript without using AJAX :(
function setContent(divName, type){ 
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = \"<select name=idp[]>"<?php echo "+ type +" ;?>"</select>\";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}

Answer (score 1):

it seems u just need one loop

```
$prod = array();

$res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products  ORDER BY name");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  if(!array_key_exists($arr['id_type'],$prod )
  {
      $prod[$arr['id_type']] =array();
  }
  $prod[$arr['id_type']][] = "<option value='".$arr['id_produktu']."'>".$arr['nazev']."</option>";               
}
```

and 
there is  no sense to do follow cause both querys are in the same table `products`

```
$types = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id_type FROM products");
```

Comment: Thx, but doesn't it replace the value of $prod['id_type'] everytime it gets the new product with already "recorded" type? or it adds the "string" to the current "string"? :) Thank you :)

Comment: you mean some different records have the same id_type?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean ;) i.e. bread and rolls are id_type=1 and cola is id_type=2 ;)

Comment: then $prod should be a double dimensional array and the code is updated